# Target debug_unpack_ios failed when trying to run Flutter app on real iOS device

Tags: ios, flutter

Target debug_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Binary /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ebamhznycvbprecszfddggy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Flutter.framework/Flutter does not contain . Running lipo -info:

I keep getting this error when I try to run the app on a real iOS device. Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated.

I have tried pod clean and install, flutter clean, cleaned contents of the DerivedData folder among some other solutions. But nothing worked for me

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?